# JavaScript - How to switch interval between sites befor they are loaded

Tags: javascript, php, html

anyone knows how i can switch between different intervals between the sites?
This is my code but i have only one interval for every site. I want to have diffrent intervals between every site. Hope anyone can help me :)

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Seitenwechsel</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="anzeige"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var anzeige;
var inhalt;
var position = 0;
var interval = 20000;
$(document).ready(function () {
    anzeige = $("#anzeige");
    inhalt = new Array("site.php", "site1.php", "site2.php", "site3.php", "site4.php");
    loadNext();
    var refresh = setInterval(function () {
                        loadNext();
                      },
                        interval
                    );
});

function loadNext() {
    anzeige.load(inhalt[position]);
    position++;
    if (position >= inhalt.length) {
        position = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change from `setInterval` to `setTimeout`, creating a new timeout based on the 'next' site in question.

Something along these lines:

```
var anzeige;
var inhalt = ["site.php", "site1.php", "site2.php", "site3.php", "site4.php"];
var interval = [20000, 40000, 3000, 20000, 60000];// num elements match inhalt array
var position = 0;
var doNext;
$(document).ready(function () {
    anzeige = $("#anzeige");
    loadNext();
});
function loadNext() {
    anzeige.load( inhalt[position] );
    position++;
    if (position >= inhalt.length) {
        position = 0;
    }
    doNext = window.setTimeout(function(){ loadNext(); }, interval[position] );
}
```

You could combine both `inhalt` and `interval` to a single javascript object if it makes it easier to rationalize it. However above I simply matched the same number of array items to each so `position` just referenced the right ones.

Edit: If you want the interval element to related to the current view page (as in, site1.php should be visible for 40 seconds, instead of 3 seconds before showing site2.php), then move the `doNext = window.setTimeout` above the `position++` line in the code. Just depends how you want to define those numbers. Time to next site, or time for current site ;)

---

You can see the above in action with this example page: http://bytejunkies.com/test/4266.php

(inspect source to see the intervals I set for those, to watch the network tab as well)

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps me a lot! :)